# Cannot bind to DataGrid Columns from within DataGridColumnHeader style template

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm using a custom defined `DataGrid` and want to be able to have a `ContextMenu` when I right click on a Column header that can alter the visibility of Columns. I have a `Style` defined for my `DataGridColumnHeader` with a template inside where I have tried to define a `ContextMenu` which takes the `DataGrid`'s Columns as it's `ItemsSource`:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type customControls:CustomDataGrid}}}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
             <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Visibility, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode = TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```

However when I right click the Column Headers to view the `ContextMenu`, nothing happens (it doesn't open as expected), and when I view the Live Property Explorer in VS I can see that the `ItemsSource` property for the `ContextMenu` is empty so it's obviously not finding the Columns property of the `DataGrid`.

Note that in the Live Visual Tree in VS I can see my `DataGridColumnHeader` style defined for the control which sits under my custom `DataGrid` in the hierarchy.

Any ideas? Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataGrid` is not a visual ancestor of the `ContextMenu`.

You could bind the `Tag` property of the `DataGridColumnHeader` to the `DataGrid` and then bind the `ContextMenu` to the `DataGrid` using the `PlacementTarget` property:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True" />
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Visibility, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityToBooleanConverter}}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Also note that you should use a `VisibilityToBooleanConverter` and not a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`:

```
class VisibilityToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Visibility visibility = (Visibility)value;
        return visibility == Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool b = (bool)value;
        return b ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: My ContextMenu is defined within the Template property for the DataGridColumnHeader so it still isn't working. I've defined the Tag property like you've done above but it seems the ItemsSource for the ContextMenu in my template cannot find the Columns property - maybe I need some different RelativeSource binding?

Comment: I've now moved the ContextMenu out of the template and set it for the DataGridColumnHeader exactly like you've done in your answer. I run the app and inspect the properties in the Live property explorer and can see the Tag property finds the DataGrid fine, but the ItemsSource still cannot find the Columns via the Tag property (it's evaluated value is empty)

Comment: Then you are obviously doing something wrong because this works for me. You should provide a MVCE when you ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You haven't mentioned anything about a Template property in your original question.